# No prompt for ssh passphrase

Tags: terminal, ssh

I have two ssh keys, one for git (gitlab) and one for a server.
My `~/.ssh/config` is :

```
Host private
  HostName x.x.x.x
  User username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server

Host git.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

However when I try `ssh username@x.x.x.x` or git commands I just have a message `Permission denied (public key)`. I have to do `ssh-add ~/.ssh/server` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/git` in order to use the keys.

How can I have a prompt to enter the passphrase the first time the key is used instead of using `ssh-add` ?
Ideally I'd prefer to have to enter my passphrase after every reboot instead of having the passphrase saved.

I am on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and I use iTerm2 with oh-my-zsh.

---

EDIT : 
After the excellent answer from wisbucky I also tried :

```
Host private
  HostName x.x.x.x
  User username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes

Host git.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

and

```
Host *
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

for the ~/.ssh/config file but without results...

Answer (score 1):

In the `~/.ssh/config`, add these lines:

```
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    # automatically add keys to keychain
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

`UseKeychain yes` will use any saved ssh keys in the Mac Keychain.

`AddKeysToAgent yes` will automatically save ssh keys in the Mac Keychain after the first time you enter the passphrase. If you don't add this, you can use `ssh-add -K` to manually add keys to the keychain also.

Note: These options were added since macOS 10.12.2

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2449/_index.html

Comment: Sadly even after adding that to `~/.ssh/config` it did not change anything... I tried to add the  `UseKeychain ` and `AddKeysToAgent ` to the previous entries and even to just let your snippet but without results. I still have to do `ssh-add key`. (I did reboot btw)